# duplicate http_accept in IE8... is it a bug?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, http-headers

I've noticed that the latest version of IE 8.0.6001.18372 sends a duplicate http_accept, like this:

```
IE8
image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, */*
```

where image/pjpeg is duplicated

I've checked with several others browsers (chrome, firefox, IE6, IE7, opera) and none of them work that way

wonder if there's a reason for sucha a behaviour or it's just a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Before shouting bug you should probably confirm that it's not been added by a Browser Helper Object or some other IE Extension.

Disable everything in the add-on manager and test again, if it doesn't go away then maybe it is a bug.